# I get an error message when I try FreqDist() in NLTK -- NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined

Tags: nltk

I'm learning about the NLTK and my mac
 is working fine except I have trouble with the FreqDist(). (I saw another question about FreqDist() but he was getting a different error message. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list')
Here's an example:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> news_text = brown.words(categories='news')
>>> fdist = nltk.FreqDist([w.lower() for w in news_text])

Traceback (most recent call last):

`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined`
```

This error message is pretty consistent. I get this message every time I try the FreqDist(). Other commands like - >>> brown.fileids() are fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16):

Before you can use FreqDist, you need to import it.

Add a line as follows:

```
import nltk
```

or if you just want to use FreqDist you should try this:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> news_text = brown.words(categories='news')
>>> fdist = FreqDist([w.lower() for w in news_text])
```

Comment: or if you want to save yourself some typing in the long term, do "from nltk import FreqDist". That will allow you to write "FreqDist" in place of "nltk.FreqDist".

Comment: I have tried all the above and still get an error when I run the above code as below:

Answer (score 1):

which means you haven't installed nltk.
follow these steps to install nltk:

1:go to this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools at the end of page you find setuptools-7.0.zip (md5) download it, then unzip it. you can find easy_install.py python script.

2:use the command sudo easy_install pip. By this time pip will be installed ready to use, (make sure you are in the directory where you can find easy_install script file).

3:use this command sudo pip install -U nltk. successful execution ensure that nltk is now installed.

4:open the IDLE then you type the following:

> > > import nltk

if nltk is installed properly then you will be returned with console.

Answer (score 0):

setuptools are required for older versions of Python. There is no need for the same if you are running 3.2+
You can easily download the same from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

For more information on http://www.nltk.org/install.html

Answer (score 0):

nltk requires data you need to download first.
Then run the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords.words("english")
```