# I get an error message when I try FreqDist() in NLTK — NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined

Tags: nltk

I have referred to the link 
[I get an error message when I try FreqDist() in NLTK -- NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476748/i-get-an-error-message-when-i-try-freqdist-in-nltk-nameerror-name-nltk-i#) 
however, I still get the error below.

[image]

Comment: This is weird because it didn't bark when you imported `brown` from `nltk.corpus`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to import nltk first to use `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist`

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.ConditionalFreqDist()
<ConditionalFreqDist with 0 conditions>
```

Or use namespaces,

```
>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
>>> ConditionalFreqDist()
<ConditionalFreqDist with 0 conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

which means you haven't installed nltk. follow these steps to install nltk:

1:go to this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools at the end of page you find setuptools-7.0.zip (md5) download it, then unzip it. you can find easy_install.py python script.

2:use the command sudo easy_install pip. By this time pip will be installed ready to use, (make sure you are in the directory where you can find easy_install script file).

3:use this command sudo pip install -U nltk. successful execution ensure that nltk is now installed.

4:open the IDLE then you type the following:

```
        import nltk
```

if nltk is installed properly then you will be returned with console.

then you can use your code without any error.

Comment: So what does your answer include that the other answer didn't? Nothing as far as I can see. You should only provide an answer if yours include a new solution to the problem. Not repeating what others have already said. I suggest you delete this answer but please don't be discouraged. Read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try again.