# When using nltk. before a nltk function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I'm new to python and using nltk, so actually I have a very basic question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere to this.

I'm wondering when to use `nltk.` before a function of the nltk module. I was working on some task and in some cases it worked without using it and in some it didn't. I'm using Jupyter Notebook. (In the examples I only wrote what I imported and the final command).

Example 1:

```
import nltk 
print (FreqDist(words).most_common(10))
```

This worked perfectly fine.

Example 2:

```
import nltk
import math

print (FreqDist(words).most_common(10))
```

gives an error message

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e68f77c40897> in <module>()
----> 1 print (FreqDist(file_words).most_common(10))

NameError: name 'FreqDist' is not defined
```

if I insert the nltk before the FreqDist it works

```
print (nltk.FreqDist(words).most_common(10))
```

Is it not working without `nltk.` in the second example because I imported two modules?

Thanks!

Comment: Example 1 & Example 2 should not work. `FreqDist()` is a method of the `nltk` package, so those examples should also have from `nltk import FreqDist` somewhere in the code for them to work (should get error `NameError: name 'FreqDist' is not defined`), otherwise the syntax `nltk.FreqDist()` should work and you may want to keep using this syntax to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also,  what error message did you get? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53197625/edit) include full text of errors in the question if the above suggestion does not help.

Comment: Are you sure Example 1 worked just fine? Essentially it is identical to code in Example 2..

Comment: You may want to review [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get an error message when I try FreqDist() in NLTK -- NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476748/i-get-an-error-message-when-i-try-freqdist-in-nltk-nameerror-name-nltk-i)

Comment: Included the error message above - Yes, I guess you're right and I'll include the `nltk import FreqDist` in the future. However, I'm still wondering why it still worked in one file and not in the other one and I'm working on them simultaneously. So, I just wanted to figure out whether there are some special rules I'm not aware of.

Comment: Unless you leaving some parts out, the code in the first one does ***not*** work, see Demo here: https://repl.it/@downshift/WelloffSuddenArchive . If you can edit and show us how it ***is*** working for you that may help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Found the problem -beginners mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Cite from `import this`:

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace):

> In general when a module is imported then the names defined in the module are defined via that module's name space, and are accessed in from the calling modules by using the fully qualified name.

For example, in Python, instead of:

```
import nltk
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('This is a sentence.'))
```

You can import do this:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
pos_tag(word_tokenize('This is a sentence.'))
```

Going back to the question, somewhere above there should be `FreqDist` imported like such:

```
from nltk import FreqDist
```

so that you can see `FreqDist` without the "fully qualified" `nltk.FreqDist`.